# ¿Usar código de styled-component como CSS y que se autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, style, template-strings

La pregunta es un poco difusa porque no sé cómo podría preguntar exáctamente lo que quiero en una sola frase. Aquí pongo dos imágenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien, en el caso de arriba el código por ejemplo no se autocompleta, y en el código de abajo sí. Digamos que lo primero lo contempla como texto dentro de una Template String y el de abajo también, pero en el de abajo sigue respetando la opción de autocompletarse del propio CSS. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que en mi código se vea como en la segunda imagen? ¿Alguna extensión o librería que lo permita?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instala la extensión vscode-styled-components

Comment: Deberías leer por favor [answer], ¿por qué instalar esa extensión resuelve el problema?

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos!